# get_the_excerpt() issues - returns the excerpt twice or not at all?

Tags: excerpt

I am experiencing a weird issue where I try and get_the_except() within my loop it brings back nothing although one has been set, also if I was to pass through the post id into the function, it gets the excerpt but shows it twice on my page.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what is the point of asking question about code without showing it?

Comment: Couple things to check - make sure you are echoing get_the_excerpt() since it returns the excerpt and does not display it. Also, make sure you don't have any theme actions/filters modifying the excerpt anywhere else.